# What are the names of current heads of peethams formed by Adi Shankaracharya in India?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, tradition

Currently, In India,
What are the names of the leading heads (peetadhipathi) of pethams formed by Adi Shankaracharya?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adi Shankaracharya established 4 mathas over India. If Kanchi is to be included, then 5.

[Govardhana Peetham](http://govardhanpeeth.org/) - H.H Shri Nischalanada Saraswati

[Sringeri Sharada peetham](https://www.sringeri.net/jagadgurus) - H.H Shri Bharathi Teertha

[Dwaraka peetham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvaraka_Pitha) - H.H Shri Swaroopanand Saraswati (also [this](http://indology.info/papers/sundaresan/shank-jyot-ascii/) site)

Jyothirmath - Currently under [dispute](http://indology.info/papers/sundaresan/shank-jyot-ascii/)

Of course, in the past century, [Kanchi](http://www.kamakoti.org/peeth/aboutpeetham.html) mutt has risen to prominence although the historical lineage, timelines are different from those accepted by the [atleast](https://www.sringeri.net/history) one other of the mathas.

[Kanchi Kamakoti peetham](http://www.kamakoti.org) is currently headed by H.H Shri Sankara Vijayendra Saraswati.