# Relations between swami Vivekananda and Shankaracharyas

Tags: advaita, vivekananda

There are [five Advaitha mathas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32063/661) in India, which were established by Adi Shankaracharya.

Swami Vivekananda was famous during his times (12 January 1863 - 4 July 1902).

Did Vivekananda meet any Shankaracharya? Did any Shankaracharya of those mathas comment about swami Vivekananda? Is there any relationship(conversation) between Vivekananda and the Shankaracharyas?

Answer (score 2):

What I do know is that Totapuri Maharaj is the one who initiated Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa into Advaita Vedanta.Apparently,one needs to be a monk to be **initiated** in Vedanta.

Tota puri Maharaj did not reside in a single place,so it was not likely for him to be associated with a single math.

https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/introduction/totapuri.htm

The above link provides information on their interaction and some discourse.

Edit:Why I mentioned Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa is the fact that he is Swami Vivekananda’s guru,and taught Swamiji Vedanta.